# POST to asp.net web api with content type x-www-form-urlencoded raises error 415 unsupported media type

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, content-type

I have developed a web service which will be called by twilio' webHook, but i'm facing an issue that my server expects a Content-type of JSon and Twilio sends a Content-type of x-www-form-urlencoded.

any help would be appreciated.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string>ProcessSms([FromBody] clsTwilio twilio)
    {

        IncomingSms incomingSms = new IncomingSms();
        incomingSms.twilio = twilio;
        return await incomingSms.ProcessSmsAsync();


    }
```

Comment: Did you see the Twilio [example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/creating-aspnet-mvc-webhook-project) ?

Answer (score 0):

`[FromBody]` can only be used for simple types. Have you tried removing `[FromBody]`?

Documentation: [Parameter binding in asp.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Answer (score 0):

After braking myself. I've changed to a GET and used the [FromQuery]  (i didn't use it before as I didn't know what the replacement for [FromUri] is. so I just figured it out)

Thanks for your assistance